# In an integral, why does logarithmic function of an exponential completely drop out?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

How to show that

$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-(x-\mu)^2 / 2\sigma^2} \ln\left[  e^{-(x-\mu)^2 / 2\sigma^2} \right] \mathrm{d} x$$

equals this:

$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-(x-\mu)^2 / 2\sigma^2}  \mathrm{d} x$$

If the exponential function appears twice in the first formula as its non-logged self multiplied by its logged self, why does the first formula reduce to an integral of only the non-logged exponential, while the logarithm completely drops out?

Comment: These are not the same. For instance, the first expression is positive while the latter is negative. Why do you think they should be equal?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac 1  {\sqrt  {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^{2}e^{-t^{2} /2 } dt=\frac 1  {\sqrt  {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2} /2 } dt$ since RHS is $1$ and LHS is the variance of the standard normal distribution which is also $1$.  Just make the substitution $t=\frac {x-\mu} {\sigma}$ or $x=\mu +\sigma t$ and you will get your identity.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$\int f(x)\ln(f(x))dx$$
$e^u=f(x)$ so: $e^udu=f'(x)dx$ or $dx=\frac{e^u}{f'(x)}du$
and so:
$$f(x)\ln(f(x))dx=ue^u\frac{e^u}{f'(x)}du$$
and now we just need to work out what $f'(x)$ is:
$$f(x)=e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}$$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}f(x)$$

---

and if we take logs of our function:
$$\ln(f(x))=-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2$$
so:
$$x-\mu=\sqrt{-2\sigma^2\ln(f(x))}$$
$$-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}=-\sqrt{\frac{-2\sigma^2\ln(f(x))}{\sigma^4}}=-\frac{\sqrt{-2\ln(f(x))}}{\sigma}=-\frac{\sqrt{-2u}}{\sigma}$$
giving:
$$f(x)\ln(f(x))dx=-ue^{2u}\sigma\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2u}e^u}du=\frac{i\sigma \sqrt{u}e^u}{\sqrt{2}}du$$
now just work out the limits, hope this helps!